# Safari: Setting image height using %

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a component that is supposed to look like this image (this is what it looks like in Chrome and Firefox):

[image: Chrome, Firefox (intended) result]

```css
.team-members {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-top: 5em;
  padding-bottom: 7.5em;
}

.team-member {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2em;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25em 1fr 2fr 0.25em;
}

.team-member__headshot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 115%;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  margin: -1em 0;
  box-shadow: 10px 20px 21px rgba(0,0,0,.16);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.team-member__text {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  padding: 4.5em 0 2.5em 5em;
}

.team-member__quote {
  color: darkblue;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.team-member__name,
.team-member__position {
  color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.team-member__name {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
  <section class="team-members">
    <div class="team-member">
      <img class="team-member__headshot" src="https://d31u1j2vbx6ya5.cloudfront.net/gei-assets/uploads/2019/08/pro-headshots-photography-tips.jpg" alt="{{ team.headshot.first().title }}">
      <div class="team-member__text">
      <p class="team-member__quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectr adipiscing elit, empor nar incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua elit, empor nar.</p>
      <p class="team-member__name">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p class="team-member__position">Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

On Safari, however, the headshot is stretching vertically with the browser window height, which consequently stretches the container (the white box):
[image: Safari result]

Any idea what I can do to fix this in Safari? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried max-height?

Comment: @Bouramas I did try max-height: 115%, but it gave the same result. I also tried putting the image inside a div and setting the div to 115% height, with the image itself at 100% height - that gave the same result in Safari.

Comment: try max-height: 400px; (be specific) and maybe some media queries. This is a hacky solution though.

Comment: @Bouramas That's my backup plan. This is in a CMS with unknown content so that hack might not work out depending on the content. Thanks though!

Comment: As you don’t know the aspect ratios of the headshots would object fit contain be better. Won’t create absolutely standard look but as it’s faces it may be more important to get them all in rather than cropped to fit.

Answer (score 0):

u can use object-fit for fill responsive image ..

add object-fit css  attrribute

```css
.team-member__headshot{


   object-fit:cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't the issue. I already have object-fit: cover on the image. The issue is that the image is not resizing vertically relative to its container's height in Safari.